# How to edit specific table records with own Admin Panel?

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update, edit, self-modifying

I simplified my code from bullshit, so we can find the problem easier.

I have a table with record from a db. I can insert new, delete an existing, but somehow I can not modify them.

When I Click the Edit button, the good one appears, but when I edit it and click the Change button, always the last row changes whatewer I tried to modofy.

Sorry for my english, I write an example:

Dog
Cat
Car
Chair

If I edit the Cat, the Chair will change... Very frustrating :D

Here is my code:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>Edit</th>
  <th>Delete</th>
</tr>

<?php 
include("connect.php");

$get_cats = "SELECT * FROM categories";
$run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);

while ($row_cats = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)) {
  $cat_id     = $row_cats['cat_id'];
  $cat_title  = $row_cats['cat_title'];
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $cat_id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $cat_title; ?></td>
    <td><a href="index.php?manage_cats&edit_cat=<?php echo $cat_id; ?>">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="index.php?manage_cats&delete_cat=<?php echo $cat_id; ?>">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?> <!-- end while -->

  <tr>
    <td>Insert New Category</td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="insert_cat_title" /></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="insert_cat" value="Insert"></td>
  </tr>

  <?php
  if(isset($_GET['edit_cat'])) {
    $edit_id     = $_GET['edit_cat'];
    $get_cat     = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_id = '$edit_id'";
    $run_cat_new = mysqli_query($con, $get_cat);

    while ($row_cat = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cat_new)) {
      $cat_id    = $row_cat['cat_id'];
      $cat_title = $row_cat['cat_title'];
  ?>
      <tr>
        <td>Change Category Name</td>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="update_cat_title" value="<?php echo $cat_title; ?>"/></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="update_cat" value="Change"></td>
      </tr>
  <?php } } ?>

</table>
</form>

<?php 

// Insert Category
if(isset($_POST['insert_cat'])) {
$cat_title = $_POST['insert_cat_title'];

if($cat_title == '') {
  echo "<script>alert('Please insert Category Name')</script>";
  echo "<script>window.open('index.php?manage_cats', '_self')</script>";
}
else {
$insert_cat = "INSERT INTO categories (cat_title) VALUES ('$cat_title')";
$run_cat    = mysqli_query($con, $insert_cat);
echo "<script>window.open('index.php?manage_cats', '_self')</script>";
}
}

// Delete Category
if(isset($_GET['delete_cat'])) {
$delete_id  = $_GET['delete_cat'];
$delete_cat = "DELETE FROM categories WHERE cat_id = '$delete_id'";
$run_delete = mysqli_query($con, $delete_cat);
echo "<script>window.open('index.php?manage_cats', '_self')</script>";
}

// Edit Category
if(isset($_POST['update_cat'])) {
$cat_title_new  = $_POST['update_cat_title'];

if($cat_title == '') {
  echo "<script>alert('Please insert Category Name')</script>";
  echo "<script>window.open('index.php?manage_cats&edit_cat', '_self')</script>";
}
else {
  $update_cat     = "UPDATE categories SET cat_title = '$cat_title_new' WHERE cat_id = '$cat_id'";
  $run_update     = mysqli_query($con, $update_cat);
  echo "<script>window.open('index.php?manage_cats', '_self')</script>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Update is running through ajax or form submit. try to echo in edit block and echo update query and see the results .

Comment: The last $cat_id is the problem but I dunno how to correct it. I need the edit_cat variable witch stores the specific ID, but I get error with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add hidden field with

`<input type="hidden" name="update_cat_id" value="<?php echo $cat_id; ?>"/>`

after

`<input type="text" name="update_cat_title" value="<?php echo $cat_title; ?>"/>`

and set with where condition like :

```
$cat_id = $_POST['update_cat_id'];
$update_cat     = "UPDATE categories SET cat_title = '$cat_title_new' WHERE cat_id = '$cat_id'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the inputs with one and the same name attribute.

will give you a query string like

http.example.com/index.php?test=1&test=2&test=3&test=4

in your URL, but in php var_dump($_GET) will return you only this

array(1) { ["test"]=> string(1) "4" }

You just overwrite the value of $_GET['test'] four times and it takes the last value.

Possible sollution:

```
<form method="get">
  <input type="text" name="test[]" value="1" />
  <input type="text" name="test[]" value="2" />
  <input type="text" name="test[]" value="3" />
  <input type="text" name="test[]" value="4" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then var_dump($_GET) gives you this:

```
array(1) { 
  ["test"]=> array(4) {
    [0]=> string(1) "1"
    [1]=> string(1) "2"
    [2]=> string(1) "3"
    [3]=> string(1) "4"
} }
```

More gentle solution is to print the categories like normal table cells (without inputs) and with jquery to convert the cell content into an input on a click on a button, link, etc

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td><a href="#">Edit</a>
    </td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td><a href="#">Edit</a>
    </td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
    <td><a href="#">Edit</a>
    </td>
    <td>Cell 4</td>
    <td><a href="#">Edit</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("td a").click(function() {
      var vvaall = $(this).parent("td").prev("td").html();
      $(this).parent("td").prev("td").empty().html('<input type="text" name="test" value="' + vvaall + '" /><input type="submit" />');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It seems logical, but I insert content dynamiccaly :/

However we solved it, but thank you anyway :)